# Multiple Unsynced versions of repo

Tags: git

Currently I have 2 unsynced versions of my repo. I tried to sync last night and because my wifi connection is fairly poor, it timed out after about an hour. I deleted some of the larger files in my repo in the hopes of being able to sync, and I also made some other changes.

**My Question:**

When I press sync, will it only attempt to sync the latest version of the repo or will it have to also sync the one from yesterday as well?

sidenote: is there any way to improve the speed of the sync besides finding a better connection?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, you'll get the whole history in your repository so yes, it'll sync the changes from yesterday as well.

What you can do, if your repo is not synced anywhere else (otherwise, you'll get into messy stuff), is to do an [interactive rebase](https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-rebase/) of your changes before you added the big files. Concretely, you find a commit that was ok and you rebase into it by editing the subsequent commits (or even leaving them out).